# How export table into excel (meteor)

Tags: html, meteor, export-to-excel

I work with Meteor (the last version).
I want to extract a HTML table into a excel document.
There is many why to do that with javascript but i can't adapt what i find with meteor.
Any help please ?
Thanks for all.

Comment: can you please explain why you need a meteor-specific solution? I don't understand why this won't work.

Comment: i try to use this jQuery plugin http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php#, in html i create a table with id="tableids" and when i click on button i call this function       $('#tableids').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'}); but i get always a blank excel file.

Comment: My antivirus won't let me access that page, but assuming it is in fact a legit package, make sure the package export can access the global namespace. You can try this in your browser console. In many cases, this means simply deleting the `var` from `var packageName = {}` at the beginning of the file.